# jquery not working in my IE extension

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, bho

I've done an IE extension in C#. The basic stuff it does is just modify the content of the page after it's loaded, basically highlights some type of text. So I have a `onDocumentComplete` handler, which adds some javascript into the `<head>` of the page, also a jquery-1.4.4.min.js:

```
public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
{
    HTMLDocument document = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser.Document;
    IHTMLElement head = (IHTMLElement)((IHTMLElementCollection)document.all.tags("head")).item(null, 0);

    IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject3 = (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
    scriptObject3.text = "/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js";
    scriptObject3.type = @"text/javascript";
    ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject3);

    IHTMLScriptElement scriptObject2 = (IHTMLScriptElement)document.createElement("script");
    scriptObject2.type = @"text/javascript";
    scriptObject2.text = "(function($) {
        $.fn.replaceText=function(b,a,c) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var f=this.firstChild,g,e,d=[];
                if(f) {
                    do {
                        if(f.nodeType===3) {
                            g=f.nodeValue;
                            e=g.replace(b,a);
                            if(e!==g){
                                if(!c&&/</.test(e)) {
                                    $(f).before(e);
                                    d.push(f)
                                }
                                else {
                                    f.nodeValue=e
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } while(f=f.nextSibling)
                }
                d.length&&$(d).remove()
            })
        }
    })(jQuery);";

    ((HTMLHeadElement)head).appendChild((IHTMLDOMNode)scriptObject2);

    ...
}
```

so both of the scripts are loaded but not working, I mean that second script uses jquery (the first script), the extension for chrome which adds same scripts  is working , so I'm thinking if it's the issue with IE.

Comment: Did you find solution?